How to get a value from radio buttons in Django form?
I have a HTML form. I need to get a value from radio button to pass it ti the model instance, but I'm getting a request without chosen radio button value, what's the problem?
product.html
<form action="{% url 'add_comment' %}" method="POST" class="addCommentForm" id="commentProductForm">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <input type="text" name="comment_text" class="search-input" id="comment_text" placeholder="Введите отзыв...">
                        <div class="rating-area">
                            <label for="star-5" title="Оценка «5»"></label> 
                            <input type="radio" id="star-5" name="rating" value="5">
                            <label for="star-4" title="Оценка «4»"></label>
                            <input type="radio" id="star-4" name="rating" value="4">
                            <label for="star-3" title="Оценка «3»"></label>  
                            <input type="radio" id="star-3" name="rating" value="3">
                            <label for="star-2" title="Оценка «2»"></label>    
                            <input type="radio" id="star-2" name="rating" value="2">
                            <label for="star-1" title="Оценка «1»"></label>
                            <input type="radio" id="star-1" name="rating" value="1">
                        </div> 
                        <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="{{ product.id }}">
                        <input type="submit" value="ОТПРАВИТЬ" class="search-btn">
                    </form>

views.py
def add_comment(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        '''
         A request like b'comment_text=r&product_id=14395&
         csrfmiddlewaretoken=2inK4JGd1nqjS79p5Z6x78IupBqMOcNGGMuFJKW8zYIN2pzMlij4hyumV7G5k0H1'

         But without choosen radio button
        '''
        print(f'\n{request.body}\n') 
        text = request.POST.get('comment_text')
        
        product_id = request.POST.get('product_id')
        stars = request.POST.get('rating') # Here it shows None

        print(f'\n\nType: {type(stars)}\nValue: {stars}\n\n')
        
        if text == '':
            return JsonResponse({'success': False, 'message': 'Invalid data'})

        profile = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
        product = Product.objects.get(id=product_id)
        
        Comment.objects.create(text=text, author=profile, product=product)
        
        return JsonResponse({'success': True, 'text': text, 'author': profile.first_name})
    
    return JsonResponse({'success': False})


To create a radio button, you need to create form not fetching data from "request.POST.get("value")" command.

@Mehdi I don't understand why value doesn't show in the POST request

Do you need sample code ?

@Mehdi No, I do understand how it works. I just have no idea why radio button value still doesn't POST to the server. It shows None whatever I do.

Try to define default checked star when form is loaded
<input type="radio" id="star-3" name="rating" value="3" checked>

